# Regular exp to match string from beginning until certain char is met

Tags: regex

I have some long string where i'm trying to catch a substring until a certain character is met.
Lets suppose I have the following string, and I would like to get the text until the first ampersand.

```
abc.8965.aghtj&hgjkiyu5.8jfhsdj
```

I would like to extract what is present before the ampersand so: abc.8965.aghtj
W thought this would work:

```
grep'^.*&{1}'
```

I would translate it as

```
^ start of string
.* match whatever chars
&{1} until the first ampersand is matched
```

Any advice?
I'm afraid this will take me weeks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{1}` does not match the first occurrence; instead it means "match exactly one of the preceding pattern/character", which is identical to just matching the character (`&{3}` would match `&&&`).

In order to match the *first* occurrence of `&`, you need to use `.*?`:

```
grep'^.*?&'
```

Normally, `.*` is greedy, meaning it matches as much as possible.  This means your pattern would match the *last* ampersand rather than the first one.  `.*?` is the non-greedy version, matching as little as possible while fulfilling the pattern.

**Update:** That syntax may not be supported by grep. Here is another option:

```
'^[^&]*&'
```

It matches anything that is not an ampersand, up to the first ampersand.

You also may have to enable extended regular expression in grep (`-E`).

Comment: grep'^.*?&' is unfortunately not working, i understand what you mean though

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
^.*?(?=&)
```

it won't get ampersand sign, just a text before it

Comment: Hi Sergio, thx, but unfortunately this is not fetchin anything

Comment: looks like you're doing smth wrong, both my and dan1111 work well, difference is that mine skips & sign

Comment: test="abc.8965.aghtj&hgjkiyu5.8jfhsdj" echo ${test} | grep '^.*?(?=&)'

Comment: @Sergio, does grep support look-ahead?